# Does AMD Ryzen support ECC?

Tags: amd-ryzen

According to many posts I'm looking for online AMD Ryzen does not support ECC at the CPU level. They advertise their premium [Threadripper as support ECC](https://www.amd.com/en/products/ryzen-threadripper),

> Quad-Channel DDR4 ECC Memory Support, With the most memory channels you can get on desktop4, the Ryzen™ Threadripper™ processor can support Workstation Standard DDR4 ECC (Error Checking & Correction Mode) Memory to keep you tight, tuned and perfectly in sync.

But does the Ryzen support it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://hardwarecanucks.com/cpu-motherboard/ecc-memory-amds-ryzen-deep-dive/), AMD has always provided ECC support in the chips but refuses to validate it (presumably to create a larger value offering in their premium enterprise line). However according to that post which tested this theory they found that of the two types of corrections ECC provides,

- recoverable, single-bit soft errors
- uncorrected errors, two or more bits

The consumer ECC implementation did not cause the motherboard to raise a fatal fault by way of hardware interrupt in the platform. This means the implementation though it exists is incomplete in the tested AM4 platform.

Answer (score 0):

ASUS claim support for a range of AM5 CPUs: https://www.asus.com/me-en/support/FAQ/1045186/ which has been verified by users to work https://old.reddit.com/r/truenas/comments/10lqofy/ecc_support_for_am5_motherboards/